# Laravel 8: Array to string conversion while calling route:list

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have a resource controller which is `ArticleController` and I want to call this controller in `web.php`, so I coded:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PanelController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController;

Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/admin/panel', [PanelController::class, 'index']);
  Route::resource('articles', [ArticleController::class]);
});
```

Then I tried the command `php artisan route:list` to check the routes but I get this error message:

> ErrorException
>
> Array to string conversion

So why this error occurs, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Route::resource` is expecting a string for the second argument, not an array.

```
Route::resource('articles', ArticleController::class);
```

Remove the call to `namespace` for the group, you don't need any namespace prefix because you are using the Fully Qualified Class Name, FQCN, to reference the Controllers.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin/panel', [PanelController::class, 'index']);
    Route::resource('articles', ArticleController::class);
});
```

Comment: I removed the array around the Controller, but now it says: `Target class [Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController] does not exist.`

Comment: Because you're adding a namespace before any controller being defined in the route file. You can check namespace in the RouteServiceProvider or the group of route that you've defined

Comment: @ruwroveajaic , i had the same issue recently, this can be fixed by putting the entire class path in a string like `Route::resource('articles', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController');`  assuming your controller is in a similar path, so you change the path accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you kept the ArticleController in a square bracket.
Remove the square bracket and Leave it like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PanelController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController;

Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/admin/panel', [PanelController::class, 'index']);
  Route::resource('articles', ArticleController::class);
});
```

**Or**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PanelController;

Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/admin/panel', [PanelController::class, 'index']);
  Route::resource('articles', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController');
});
```

The resource method is expecting a reference to the controller class as second parameter but you gave it an array.

**Note**
if you are using the first snippet, make sure the class is correctly imported.Else you will run into another error.